# Is there some library to help me to write Javascript code in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript

I'm looking for something to help me to write C# code that would be automatically converted to javascript. The advantage would be code-completion and type-safety.

Some features that I'm looking for are the following:

- Auto creation of prototype equivalents to C# classes.
- Auto generation of javascript code based on C# code (property settings, method calls...)
- Exposition of Javascript types such as Window, Document and etc.

Is there something like that out there?

Comment: That would be a nice piece of magic if it exists.

Comment: You mean something like Google Web Toolkit (http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/webtoolkit/overview.html), but for .net, not for Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp).

Comment: nikhilk's blog posts are always awesome - I didn't realize he was the author of this tool also!